# How to add collapse up/down icon for accordion table

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4, accordion

Well am trying to develop an accordion table for showing the result. However am not happy with design and tried to add a collapse arrow to table rows for indicating that there is a nested table. Unfortunately it doesn't worked. May I know how can I add this by going below code snipneet

```js
$('.accordion-toggle').click(function() {
  $('.hiddenRow').hide();
  $(this).next('tr').find('.hiddenRow').show();
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #004C70 !important;
}

.table tr {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.table {
  background-color: #fff !important;
}

.hedding h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.main-section {
  margin-top: 120px;
}

.hiddenRow {
  padding: 0 4px !important;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.accordian-body span {
  color: #a2a2a2 !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Table Row Toggel </title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="custom.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
    body{
    background-color:#004C70 !important;
}
.table tr {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.table{
    background-color: #fff !important;
}
.hedding h1{
    color:#fff;
    font-size:25px;
}
.main-section{
    margin-top: 120px;
}
.hiddenRow {
    padding: 0 4px !important;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    font-size: 13px;
}
.accordian-body span{
    color:#a2a2a2 !important;
}

</style>
<body>
    <div class="container main-section">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 hedding pb-2">
                <h1> TEsting </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <table class="table table-bordered" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                    <thead>
                        <th>Testing</th>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Activity</th>
                            <th>Time</th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                            <th>Corrective Measure</th>
                            <th>Comment</th>
                            
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr colspan="6" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo1" class="accordion-toggle">
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td>12 Jan 2018</td>
                            <td>Good</td>
                            <td>$150.00</td>
                            <td> - </td>
                            
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="p">
                            <td colspan="6" class="hiddenRow">
                                <div class="accordian-body collapse p-3" id="demo1">
                                    <p>No : <span>1</span></p>
                                    <p>Date : <span>12 Jan 2018</span> </p>
                                    <p>Description : <span>Good</span> </p>
                                    <p>Credit : <span>$150.00</span> </p>
                                    <p>Debit : <span></span></p>
                                    <p>Balance : <span>$150.00</span></p>
                                </div> 
                            </td> 
                        </tr>
                        <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo2" class="accordion-toggle">
                            <td>2</td>
                            <td>12 Jan 2018</td>
                            <td>Good</td>
                            <td>$11.00</td>
                            <td> - </td>
                            
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="6" class="hiddenRow">
                                <div id="demo2" class="accordian-body collapse p-3">
                                    <p>No : <span>2</span></p>
                                    <p>Date : <span>12 Jan 2018</span> </p>
                                    <p>Description : <span>Good</span> </p>
                                    <p>Credit : <span>$150.00</span> </p>
                                    <p>Debit : <span></span></p>
                                    <p>Balance : <span>$150.00</span></p>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        
                        <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo3" class="accordion-toggle">
                            <td>3</td>
                            <td>12 Jan 2018</td>
                            <td>Good</td>
                            <td>$500.00</td>
                            <td> - </td>
                            
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="6"  class="hiddenRow">
                                <div id="demo3" class="accordian-body collapse p-3">
                                    <p>No : <span>3</span></p>
                                    <p>Date : <span>12 Jan 2018</span> </p>
                                    <p>Description : <span>Good</span> </p>
                                    <p>Credit : <span>$150.00</span> </p>
                                    <p>Debit : <span></span></p>
                                    <p>Balance : <span>$150.00</span></p>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo4" class="accordion-toggle">
                            <td>4</td>
                            <td>12 Jan 2018</td>
                            <td>Good</td>
                            <td>$500.00</td>
                            <td> - </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="6"  class="hiddenRow">
                                <div id="demo4" class="accordian-body collapse p-3">
                                    <p>No : <span>4</span></p>
                                    <p>Date : <span>12 Jan 2018</span> </p>
                                    <p>Description : <span>Good</span> </p>
                                    <p>Credit : <span>$150.00</span> </p>
                                    <p>Debit : <span></span></p>
                                    <p>Balance : <span>$150.00</span></p>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo5" class="accordion-toggle">
                            <td>5</td>
                            <td>12 Jan 2018</td>
                            <td>Good</td>
                            <td>$500.00</td>
                            <td> - </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="6"  class="hiddenRow">
                                <div id="demo5" class="accordian-body collapse p-3">
                                    <table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td colspan="2">Larry the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>       
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('.accordion-toggle').click(function(){
    $('.hiddenRow').hide();
    $(this).next('tr').find('.hiddenRow').show();
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

May i know how can I add collapse arrow to the accordian ?

Answer (score 0):

Add a couple of icons and hide/show them based on the `.collapsed` state of the row.

For example:

```
<style>
   ...
   tr.collapsed .icon-arrow-down { display: none; }
   tr:not(.collapsed) .icon-arrow-up { display: none; }
</style>

<tr ...>
  <td>
     <i class="icon-arrow-down"></i>
     <i class="icon-arrow-up"></i>
  </td>
  ...
</tr>
```

Comment: It is not working. Could you try in the attached code snippet

Answer (score 0):

I would use "CSS before" or "CSS after" pseudo elements to create arrow for each row with class `accordion-toggle`, so you won't need to import any icon or library.
I edited your CSS and added the pseudo element at the end of it, but you should probably work on design and positioning of the arrow.

```js
$('.accordion-toggle').click(function() {
  $('.hiddenRow').hide();
  $(this).next('tr').find('.hiddenRow').show();
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #004C70 !important;
}

.table tr {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.table {
  background-color: #fff !important;
}

.hedding h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.main-section {
  margin-top: 120px;
}

.hiddenRow {
  padding: 0 4px !important;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.accordian-body span {
  color: #a2a2a2 !important;
}

.accordion-toggle::before {
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  right: 1.5em;
  margin-top: 1.5em
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Table Row Toggel </title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="custom.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
    body{
    background-color:#004C70 !important;
}
.table tr {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.table{
    background-color: #fff !important;
}
.hedding h1{
    color:#fff;
    font-size:25px;
}
.main-section{
    margin-top: 120px;
}
.hiddenRow {
    padding: 0 4px !important;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    font-size: 13px;
}
.accordian-body span{
    color:#a2a2a2 !important;
}

</style>
<body>
    <div class="container main-section">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 hedding pb-2">
                <h1> TEsting </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <table class="table table-bordered" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                    <thead>
                        <th>Testing</th>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Activity</th>
                            <th>Time</th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                            <th>Corrective Measure</th>
                            <th>Comment</th>
                            
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr colspan="6" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo1" class="accordion-toggle">
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td>12 Jan 2018</td>
                            <td>Good</td>
                            <td>$150.00</td>
                            <td> - </td>
                            
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="p">
                            <td colspan="6" class="hiddenRow">
                                <div class="accordian-body collapse p-3" id="demo1">
                                    <p>No : <span>1</span></p>
                                    <p>Date : <span>12 Jan 2018</span> </p>
                                    <p>Description : <span>Good</span> </p>
                                    <p>Credit : <span>$150.00</span> </p>
                                    <p>Debit : <span></span></p>
                                    <p>Balance : <span>$150.00</span></p>
                                </div> 
                            </td> 
                        </tr>
                        <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo2" class="accordion-toggle">
                            <td>2</td>
                            <td>12 Jan 2018</td>
                            <td>Good</td>
                            <td>$11.00</td>
                            <td> - </td>
                            
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="6" class="hiddenRow">
                                <div id="demo2" class="accordian-body collapse p-3">
                                    <p>No : <span>2</span></p>
                                    <p>Date : <span>12 Jan 2018</span> </p>
                                    <p>Description : <span>Good</span> </p>
                                    <p>Credit : <span>$150.00</span> </p>
                                    <p>Debit : <span></span></p>
                                    <p>Balance : <span>$150.00</span></p>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        
                        <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo3" class="accordion-toggle">
                            <td>3</td>
                            <td>12 Jan 2018</td>
                            <td>Good</td>
                            <td>$500.00</td>
                            <td> - </td>
                            
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="6"  class="hiddenRow">
                                <div id="demo3" class="accordian-body collapse p-3">
                                    <p>No : <span>3</span></p>
                                    <p>Date : <span>12 Jan 2018</span> </p>
                                    <p>Description : <span>Good</span> </p>
                                    <p>Credit : <span>$150.00</span> </p>
                                    <p>Debit : <span></span></p>
                                    <p>Balance : <span>$150.00</span></p>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo4" class="accordion-toggle">
                            <td>4</td>
                            <td>12 Jan 2018</td>
                            <td>Good</td>
                            <td>$500.00</td>
                            <td> - </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="6"  class="hiddenRow">
                                <div id="demo4" class="accordian-body collapse p-3">
                                    <p>No : <span>4</span></p>
                                    <p>Date : <span>12 Jan 2018</span> </p>
                                    <p>Description : <span>Good</span> </p>
                                    <p>Credit : <span>$150.00</span> </p>
                                    <p>Debit : <span></span></p>
                                    <p>Balance : <span>$150.00</span></p>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo5" class="accordion-toggle">
                            <td>5</td>
                            <td>12 Jan 2018</td>
                            <td>Good</td>
                            <td>$500.00</td>
                            <td> - </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="6"  class="hiddenRow">
                                <div id="demo5" class="accordian-body collapse p-3">
                                    <table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td colspan="2">Larry the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>       
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('.accordion-toggle').click(function(){
    $('.hiddenRow').hide();
    $(this).next('tr').find('.hiddenRow').show();
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. How can we bring that arrow in the begin of row instead of at end

Comment: I used `right: 1.5em;` in CSS properties for placing the arrow on right side of the row, you can use `left: 1.5em` instead, or any amount which fits.